# laravel4 update migration file in live server

Tags: php, laravel-4

This is a very basic question about laravel.

i have a migration file something like that

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateDonorsTable extends Migration {

/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('donors', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');

        $table->string('donor_name');

        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('blood_group');
        $table->string('phone_number')->unique()->nullable();
        $table->string('location');
        $table->date('date_of_birth');
        $table->date('last_date_of_donation');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('donors');
}

}
```

and i have already migrated my database using this migration file and **uploaded it in a live server**. now i have to update my migration file and have to add a new field namely `donor_image`.

how can i do this in a live server?what is the best possible way to update the migration file after uploading a larvel project in a live server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice is to make *another* migration file with just the changes (such as adding a column).

Then you run the new migration - which only makes the sub-set of changes listed.

Changing the original migration file is incorrect - and you now cannot use it to apply the changes (without destroying the original table).

Comment: but it seems according to your answer,that i have to do this locally using cmd,is it?if it is,then my question is, how can i do this directly for live server?

Comment: 1. Make new migration file. 2. Get migration file onto the server (either via git update, or copy it over). 3. Run `php artisan migrate` on the live server